buildkite - can I add manual post build activities that don't prevent the build from being shown as complete?
in buildkite - we have a number of steps that build, test, deploy etc - but often people are putting in a manual block of a wait with a "destroy" stack step at the end.   That works fine - but in the list of builds, because those steps have not been run - the build is showing with a paused sign in the list of builds - it's hard to see which ones have been successfully promoted - because they also have a pause before the promotion to prod.
Is there a way of including steps that can be run after a build, like cleanup steps or other manual steps that occasionally get run - but having the build show as complete regardless of whether these steps ever get clicked?
